# How to update data point in highcharts which is not in the visible range

Tags: highcharts

I tried to update the last data point on the right side of OHLC chart but `series.data[series.data.length - 1]` always returns the last data point from the visible range. Is it possible to update the last data point irrespective of whether it is in the visible range or not?

Comment: You can refer to series.options.data and update value, including setExtremes. example: http://jsfiddle.net/pxc9pc29/

Comment: If user has moved the navigator scroller, setting extremes moves it back to the extreme position set by setExtremes. What I want is, irrespective of where the user has moved the navigator scroller, I want to update the last OHLC on right side of the chart(in the invisible area). addPoint() works correctly. addPoint always adds at the end and does not matter if that point is in the visible area or not. Can we not have something similar and simple for update?